# Notice: Undefined index: Extension in C:\

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo el siguiente codigo :

```js
function envioparametro() {

    var fData = new FormData();
    fData.append("Extenso","pdf,PDF");
    fData.append("Tamano", 2014);
    $.ajax({
        url : 'subir.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: fData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }

    });

}
```

el alert me arroja los datos del data lo cual se muestra así:  pdf,PDF2014Extension lo cual no se si sea correcto, en el lado PHP estoy tratando de recuperar los valores asi:

```html
$datoExtension = $_POST["Extenso"];
$datoTamanio = $_POST['Tamano'];
```

y me arroja el siguiente error Notice: Undefined index: Extenso in C:\xampp\htdocs\Subir_archivos\subir.php on line 4  y 5 respectivamente...

No encuentro como evitar este error.

Gracias

Saludos

NikolaTesla ya hice exactamente lo que me comentas dejando el código así :

```html
if(isset($_POST["Extenso"])  || ($_POST['Tamano']))
            {
                $Extension = $_POST["Extenso"];
                $Tamanio = $_POST['Tamano'];

                echo ("Este valor si entra desde el isset  ".$Extension );
                echo ("Este valor si entra desde el isset  ".$Tamanio );

                $archivo_nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
                $archivo_tamanio = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
                $archivo_tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
                $archivo_nombre_temporal = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];  }
```

el problema que he tenido desde el principio es que aunque reciba estos valores me truena las siguientes lineas de código `$archivo_nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];` siempre me dice que archivo no esta definido.

lo he intentado de varias maneras de hecho es parte del tema de un javascript que "controla" el HTML para recibir un archivo, modificar la barra de progreso y botones de acción,  pero se me ha complicado mucho realizar una simple validación teniendo que pasar por ese javascript.

Comment: Date cuenta que lo que se están enviando por POST al servidor tiene como clave el atributo `name` de tus campos (input, select, textarea...) Si subieras el HTML de tu `<form>` se podría ver más al respecto.

Comment: No estoy enviando nada mas que los datos señalados en la función a través del uso del formData utilizando esta estructura  fData.append("Extenso","pdf,PDF"); y  fData.append("Tamano", 2014); solo necesito recuperar en el PHP con el POST

Comment: Pon un `var_dump($_POST);` y dinos qué muestra. Así se podrá revisar qué datos están llegando y bajo qué estructura. Cabe decir que para usar bien `FormData` debes declarar el formulario como multi-part.

Comment: @A.Cedano, este es un tema derivado de otro que ya has leido, tengo un archivo php que se encarga de realizar operaciones sobre el nombre de un archivo para subirlo y guardarlo en cierta carpeta, con eso no hay problema funciona bien,  el problema es que se tiene que validar el tamaño y la extension,  y el javascript tiene el control del HTML y del archivo php , se supone que es javascript puro, yo no lo escribi, y me ha dado muchos problemas este codigo, pero asi lo quieren en mi trabajo

Comment: @A.Cedano de hecho ni siquiera en el form tengo en esta linea --> enctype="multipart/form-data" ya que el JavaScript se encarga de hacer la peticion y enviar el archivo al php que se encarga de subir , como te digo a mi de entrada no me gusto ese codigo, pero mi jefe dice que por ahi es la linea y hay que resolverlo

Comment: Entiendo, entonces depura el POST como te dije con `var_dump($_POST);` y dinos cómo vienen los datos.

Comment: [Lee esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158711/29967), pues allí ocurrió en el caso concreto de ese OP que necesitó usar `parse_str` para leer la parte de FormData que no eran archivos. Lo he explicado al final de la respuesta, en el apartado titulado **PostData**, puede que aquí también estés necesitando usar `parse_str` ¿?

Comment: No estás agregando el archivo a `fData`. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/208113/como-puedo-subir-un-archivo-a-mi-servidor-mediante-php-ajax-javascript#answer-208237) para ver cómo hacerlo.

Comment: @Triby Hola Paisano, No , no se esta agregando el archivo a este fdata, ya que el archivo se envía desde un JavaScript que tiene esta "peticion" :  peticion.open('post','subir.php');
peticion.send(new FormData(form)); ya se intento enviar desde esta petición los atributos para validar el archivo y sin éxito.  Me dijeron búscale y pues ya llevo una semana y lo que va de esta buscándole.  Saludos

Comment: Creo que no se puede pre-cargar en subir.php los valores predefinidos para poder validar la extensión y el tamaño del archivo antes que se tomen  los datos del archivo desde $_FILES , ya que recibo los datos de "validación" en el POST truena siempre lo que corresponde a $_FILES , en cuanto hago eso me dice que no conoce la variable "archivo" que va en $archivo_nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name']; de una por una me indica eso, y  pues ya ni carga el archivo y puras falla....

Comment: @Cesarin, compadre, tienes que colocar todo el código involucrado y contarnos qué es exactamente lo que quieres hacer, pero con lujo de detalle, a fin de cuentas, no cobran por preguntas extensas.

Comment: @Triby en este enlace te pongo el HTML y el Javascript que se esta utilizando, es una aportación de un tercero... https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/396330/como-se-puede-pasar-parametros-a-esta-funcion/396339#396339  El Javascript se encarga de los botones, de la barra y del envio del archivo, era lo que le decia a A.Cedano que ni siquiera le he puesto ene el form enctype="multipart/form-data" por que ni siquiera se ocupa así como esta hecho este código. entonces dejame ampliar en el enlace que te mando.  Saludos

Comment: Listo ya amplie algunas cosas en lo que corresponde al PHP  el enlace es este:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/396330/como-se-puede-pasar-parametros-a-esta-funcion  la idea es validar que el archivo recibido antes de ser procesado y enviado al servidor cumpla con el tamaño y extensión valida. la restricción es que se hiciera una función pero se me ha complicado.

Comment: Me parece que estás enviando dos peticiones, una con datos de validación y otra con el archivo y el problema es que quieres tener todo junto. Por eso es importante que nos cuentes cómo es todo el proceso, por ejemplo: 1) Se crea formulario ¿PHP puede modificarlo? 2) El usuario interactúa y se generan las variables 3) El usuario selecciona un archivo 4) Se envía a PHP... ¿qué pasa o qué debe pasar?

Comment: @Triby, el formulario no trae mas que el input para cargar el archivo, un botón de envió y uno de cancelar, es lo único que puede interactuar el usuario,  asi tal cual como esta el codigo enviar el archivo a la carpeta indicada, la idea es validar el archivo que cumpla solamente con el tipo de archivo y el tamaño permitido es todo.....pero no me sale jajaja

Answer (score 1):

Te Recomiendo que utilices la funcion `isset` antes de asignar lo que traes en POST a una variable por ejemplo:

```
<?php
     if( isset($_POST["Extenso"]) && isset($_POST["Tamano"]) ) {
        $datoExtension = $_POST["Extenso"];
        $datoTamanio = $_POST['Tamano'];
     }
?>
```

Te dejo un enlace para que profundices mas en el tema:

[Isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php)

Comment: Si ya lo hice, tal cual como comentas, y puse unos echo : 
    
                echo ("Este valor si entra desde el isset  ".$Extenso );
                echo ("Este valor si entra desde el isset  ".$Tamano );  }

Comment: ¿Y te sigue saliendo el error? puedes mostrar un echo de var_dump($_POST) y decirnos que te muestra ?